# Foundation 6.7.4 installation issue (scss) : Node modules not installed

Tags: node.js, installation, sass, zurb-foundation, yarnpkg

I was in search of the page below on zurb-foundation to get my custom css and js files based on the flex-grid. Unfortunately, the page is no longer available...

[image: ZURB FOUNDATION CUSTOMIZE PAGE]

I was afraid of scss but I decided to try. Sadly, my little experiments confirm my fears, it's not user friendly at all... Why can't we just download a zip file and just let's go ?
I have followed the instructions found on the internet.

Firstly, software installations (as recommended on this video) : [Windows Install ZURB Foundation 6.0](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjpvKq-kYT0AhXDB2MBHUEODb8QwqsBegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DJKywQK4NPdc&usg=AOvVaw3n0_TTKtgGiiGVN9zNnBap)
_ Git-2.33.1-64-bit.exe
_ node-v16.13.0-x64.msi

Then I opened Windows 10 cmd panel and I wrote the command lines as recommended :

```
$ npm install foundation-sites
$ npm install --global foundation-cli
$ foundation new
```

And I've got an error message with the indication below :
Node modules not installed. Try running yarn install manually.
Complete results below.

I've tried so many things (with yarn, ruby, on my xubuntu partition) but the result is always the same...

If someone knows a solution It would be a pleasure to listen advices.

```
> Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19042.1288]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\Name>npm install foundation-sites

added 4 packages, and audited 5 packages in 4s

found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\Name>npm install --global foundation-cli

removed 222 packages, changed 184 packages, and audited 218 packages in 15s

27 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

1 moderate severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

C:\Users\Name>foundation new
? What are you building today? A website (Foundation for Sites)
? What's the project called? (no spaces) myproject
? Which template would you like to use? Basic Template: includes a Sass compiler

            .
           /|     ,
      , /|/  \/| /|       Thanks for using Foundation for Sites!
     /|/       |/ |       -------------------------------------------
 |___|            |___|   Let's set up a new project.
 \___|  ^^   ^^   |___/   It shouldn't take more than a minute.
     | -[O]--[O]- |
     |    ___,    |
     |    ...     |
      \__________/


Downloading the project template...
Done downloading!

Installing dependencies...


up to date, audited 5 packages in 12s

found 0 vulnerabilities
undefined

There were some problems during the installation.

 ✓ New project folder created.
 ✗ Node modules not installed. Try running yarn install manually.

Once you've resolved the above issues, run foundation watch while inside the myproject folder.


C:\Users\Name>
```

Comment: When you run `npm i` manually, you should see the actual errors.